# <NAME> name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, controltemplate, wpf-animation

Just yesterday in very similar situation this code was working on the exactly the same machine.. Today it throws an exception..

> "'SelectedContentBorder' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'."

Here is it:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
   <Border Name="SelectedContentBorder">
      <ContentPresenter Name="ContentPresenter" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectionChanged">
         <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation 
                  From="0" 
                  To="1" 
                  Duration="00:00:0.5"
                  Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedContentBorder"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Whats wrong with that?

Comment: Works for me. Maybe a simple clean solution can help?

Comment: @jHilscher No, that doesnt work. In truth, I am extremely tired from WPF, but there is no alternative for windows-desktop on C#.

Comment: You must be adding this ControlTemplate using code.